# How to Include ./DirA/DirB/Here in Matlab's Working Directory?

Tags: matlab, path

I do

- Press "Run" symbol in the function which you want to run, to just change working directory to the location of the function.
- However, the function changes the working Directory.

  ```
  function hello(start,end)

  if (exist('old_path', 'var') == 0) 

      [old_path]=which('rdsamp');if(~isempty(old_path)) rmpath(old_path(1:end-8)); end
      wfdb_url='http://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip';
      [filestr,status] = urlwrite(wfdb_url,'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip');%Octave users may have to download manually
      unzip('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip');
      cd wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9;cd mcode
      addpath(pwd);savepath ./pathdef.m
  end
  end
  ```

Path after running the function

[image]

I am confused how to manage wfdb code in relation to your working directory.

Suever's proposal

- Works if adding `hello.m` in Matlab's path
- Does not work if not adding `hello.m` in Matlab's path

System: Ubuntu 16.04
Matlab: 2016a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change directories inside of your code. Instead, add the toolbox directory to your path from within your code. You can pass a directory to `addpath` as a string rather than using `pwd`.

```
addpath(fullfile('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9', 'mcode'))
```

Also consider adding the path where `hello.m` is located to your path (or navigate to that directory first) and run it from the command line as `hello` rather than hitting the run button.

Comment: Doing `Add path` the function. Then, running the thing - things work. However, still I cannot run `hello.m` in Terminal. Only in Matlab's prompt.

Comment: @Masi I was referring to Matlab's command line *not* the system terminal

Comment: Do you understand the first error when not using *Add to Path*?